# Lie algebra/group/basis of the four gamma matrices along with the identity?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Do the four gamma matrices along with the identity element constitute a lie algebra?

With real coefficients we have

$$
\mathbf{v}_{\mathbb{R}}=aI+t\gamma_0+x\gamma_1+y\gamma_2+z\gamma_3 \tag{real coefficients}
$$

or using complex coefficients  as
$$
\mathbf{v}_\mathbb{C}=z_a I+ z_0 \gamma_0+z_1 \gamma_1+z_2\gamma_2+z_2\gamma_3. \tag{complex coefficients}
$$

---

What Lie algebra is associated with $\{1, \gamma_0, \gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3 \}$?

I am already familiar with this question [Do gamma matrices form a basis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101887/do-gamma-matrices-form-a-basis), stating that the 16 basis of the Clifford algebra forms a basis of $M(4,\mathbf{C})$, but what about the 5 elements of $\{1, \gamma_0, \gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3 \}$?

---

Based on the comments here is the commutator of $\mathbf{v}_{\mathbb{R}}$.

$$
[\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}]=\mathbf{v}_{1}\mathbf{v}_{2}-\mathbf{v}_{2}\mathbf{v}_{1}
$$

Using 1+1 to simplify, we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
[\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2}] &&= (a+b\gamma_0)(c+d\gamma_0)-(c+d\gamma_0)(a+b\gamma_0)\\
&&=(ac+ad\gamma_0+bc\gamma_0+bd\gamma_0^2)-(ca+cb\gamma_0+da\gamma_0+db\gamma_0^2)\\
&&=(ac-ac)+(ad-ad)\gamma_0+(bc-bc)\gamma_0+(bd-bd)\gamma_0^2\\
&&=0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: OP's vector spaces endowed with the commutator do not form a Lie algebra. However, they generate (in the algebra sense) the Lie algebra $gl(4,\mathbb{F})$.

Comment: @Qmechanic can you tell me which property of the lie bracket fails for this vector space?

Comment: $[\gamma,\gamma]\neq\sum z_i\gamma_i$

Comment: $\gamma_0$ commutes with itself and with the identity, of course.

Comment: @CosmasZachos So then, is the basis $\{1, \gamma_0,\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3\}$ a lie algebra? And if so, of which group.

Comment: ***No*** !  You know the $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$ of QED is linearly independent of these. My only point is that getting a trivial commutator of a γ and the identity cannot *possibly*  suggest a Lie algebra! Do you know of any matrix that would not do that?

Comment: $\mathrm{span}(1,\gamma^0)=\mathfrak u_1\oplus\mathfrak u_1$ and $\mathrm{span}(1,\gamma^0,\gamma^1,\gamma^2)=\mathfrak u_2$. Other than that, the commutator is not a Lie bracket.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your set is not closed. For example,
$$
[\gamma_0,\gamma_1]=\gamma_0\gamma_1 - \gamma_1\gamma_0 = \gamma_0\gamma_1 + \gamma_0\gamma_1= 2\gamma_0\gamma_1
$$
lies outside the said set. (BTW, the identity element $1$ or $I$ belongs to the *Lie group*, not the *Lie algebra*.)

If you set out to find a closed Lie algebra, the above suggests that you have to include 
$$
\gamma_0\gamma_1
$$
into the mix. And if you goof around further, you would stumble upon the 10-element closed set
$$
\{\gamma_0, \gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3,  \gamma_0\gamma_1, \gamma_0\gamma_2, \gamma_0\gamma_3, \gamma_1\gamma_2, \gamma_2\gamma_3, \gamma_3\gamma_1 \},
$$
which turns out to be a bona fide Lie algebra.

What could this 10-element Lie algebra be? It's no other than the de Sitter algebra
$$
so(1, 4)
$$
which corresponds to the 5-dimensional rotation group.

If you are an able college student, you would recognize that the 6-element subset 
$$
\{\gamma_0\gamma_1, \gamma_0\gamma_2, \gamma_0\gamma_3, \gamma_1\gamma_2, \gamma_2\gamma_3, \gamma_3\gamma_1 \}
$$
constitutes the Lorentz algebra $so(1,3)$, which is tied to 4-dimensional space-time rotation.

If you are the curious bunch, you might also wonder what can the subset 
$$
\{\gamma_0, \gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3\}
$$
be?

The straight forward interpretation is that they are the 4 rotations alone the planes spanned by the 5th 
 dimension and each 4 space-time dimension (did we mention that de Sitter is 5-dimensional rotation?). In math jargon, they form the coset 
$$
so(1, 4)/so(1,3).
$$

That said, we can look at them from a different angle: if we re-scale the identity we pondered on earlier
$$
[\gamma_0,\gamma_1]=\epsilon\gamma_0\gamma_1 \rightarrow 0 (\epsilon \rightarrow 0)
$$
which means your New Year wish is granted, i.e. the gamma matrices commute with each other, we can thus identify  $\{\gamma_0, \gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3\}$ with the space-time translation symmetry (recalling that the Dirac derivative $\not \partial = \gamma^\mu \partial_{\mu}$ couples the space-time translations $\partial_{\mu}$ with the gamma matrices $\gamma^\mu$). Then the whole 10-element de Sitter algebra transmutes into the semi-simple Poincare algebra.